# How to add Push Notification in Vue(non ionic) + Capacitor?

Tags: android, firebase, vue.js, notifications, capacitor

I couldn't find any detail documentation on this, I need to receive notification from firebase to my vue mobile app (android). Also I need docs on how to send push from backend like php or nodejs.

I tried find all docs and tutorial but couldn't found any with this specific situation : Vue (not-ionic) or Vuetify with Capacitor.

Comment: This isn't specific to Vue in any way. It's like that https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications . You'd need a websocket or long polling to be able to send messages from the back end